# How to synchronize data from iPhone to iPod?

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, ipod

My iPhone was stolen. I always backed up with iCloud and my computer (Windows PC) through iTunes.
I have decided to completely block and erase my iPhone remotely but I want to keep the data (at least contacts) to a device I own. my iCloud account shows 5GB used and has contacts in it.
Will that data be erased if I erase my iPhone?

Also, I want to synchronize stored iPhone backup from my iCloud and PC to my iPod but iTunes does not show any such option when my iPod is connected to the PC.
I'm doing something like this for first time and Apple's support pages on this topic do not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you backed your iPhone up and saved it to iCloud, you can do the following:

Before you do it, Make sure to backup the iPod!

> On your iOS device, go to Settings > General > Software Update. If a newer version of iOS is available, follow the onscreen instructions to download and install it.
>
> Make sure you have a recent backup to restore from.
>
> On your iOS 8 device: Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage, then tap a device listed under Backups to see the date and size of its latest backup.
>
> On your iOS 7 device: Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage, then tap a device listed under Backups to see the date and size of its latest backup.
>
> For information about backing up manually now, see Back up your iOS device to iCloud. If you don’t see a backup you expected to be there, see the Apple Support article If you need help restoring from an iCloud backup.
>
> Go to Settings > General > Reset, then tap “Erase all content and settings.”
>
> In the Setup Assistant, proceed to “Set up your device,” tap Restore from a Backup, then sign in to iCloud.
>
> Proceed to “Choose backup,” then choose from a list of available backups in iCloud.
>
> For help deciding which backup to restore from, including information about restoring from another device’s backup, see the Apple Support article If you need help restoring from an iCloud backup.

---

Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_US

---

However, this will delete all the data on the iPod and put the iPhone data in. Ignore the iOS 7 and iOS 8. They are there for distinguishment.